# Reaction arrows with reaction rates with subscripts with mhchem and Sphinx

Tags: mhchem

I am using [Sphinx 1.1.3](http://sphinx-doc.org/) to document a reaction rate with an underscore.

```
\ce{A + $h$\nu ->[k_A] B}
```

It works perfectly when I make html documentation, using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) and a template file containing the following:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}

{% block extrahead %} 
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
        extensions: ["mhchem.js"]
    }
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and including the `_templates` folder in the `templates_path` of the `conf.py` file.

You can see [my mchem_example here](http://bwanamarko.alwaysdata.net/mhchem_example/mhchem_example.html).

But when I try to build a latexpdf using [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/), with the preamble `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}` as stated in the [mhchem documentation](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) in the `latex_elements` dictionary of the `conf.py`, I don't get the reaction rate or the arrow. The other examples in the mhchem documentation all work, such as using `+H20` or `\alpha`. I have made it work for both MathJax and MiKTeX by enclosing the `\nu` in curly braces.

```
\ce{A + $h${\nu} ->[k_A] B}
```

So now my question is why? Why does the `\nu` have to be in curly braces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is TeX's 'skipping spaces after control sequences' behaviour coming into play.  TeX ignorres spaces after control sequences, so here after `\nu`. That means that `mhchem` 'sees'

```
A + $h$\nu->[k_A] B
```

However, `mhchem` uses spaces to determine exactly things like arrows are. As a result, the space between `\nu` and `-` is needed to get things to parse correctly. Your solution works as it stops the space skipping: an alternative would be `$h$\nu{}`. I'd actually go for

```
A + $h\nu$ ->[k_A] B
```

as the `h\nu` really forms one mathematical entity (rather than a compound symbol).

I guess MathJax doesn't quite respect TeX's usual parsing rules here, so doesn't do the space skipping.